# Symfonys 2 app_dev.php gives a blank page while app.php works perfectly

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to start a new project with Symfony2. I started with a simple Hello world. Controller:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $name = 'world';
    return $this->render('MyowntestBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
}
}
```

View:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}

Hello {{ name }}!

{% endblock %}
```

When i open site through `app.php` everything is ok, but opening `app_dev.php` results in a blank, white page. Nothing in apache main error log, nothing in vhost error log and `app/logs/dev.log` is empty too.

Whats wrong?

Comment: See what's the difference between `app.php` and `app_dev.php`. That way you can see what's causing your problem.

Comment: Use `F12` to open your dev tools, then refresh to check the status code you're getting back. You also may want to clear `Apc` (if any) and `Symfony` cache.

Comment: Check dev.log or php error log for details

Answer (score 0):

app_dev only works when testing on the same server. 
meaning you're on your WAMP/XAMP etc..

To enable using app_dev.php, open it and comment out the following:

```
       if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
   || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
   || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
```

) {
       header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
       exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(**FILE**).' for more information.');
   }

you can find app_dev.php in the web/app_dev.php directory.

Good luck !

Comment: I commented out that part as first thing done in project, so its not that.

Comment: Did you try any function other than the hello world that is already present in the demo project?

Answer (score 0):

Problems gone after updating PHP to 5.4. Dont know what was exactly wrong.